# What should I do if a refund from XMR.to did not include a payment ID

Tags: xmr.to, refund

I'm new to Monero (actually all crypto). Long story short is that I created an order on [XMR.to](https://xmr.to) and it timed out before I could deposit 100%.

XMR.to messaged me and said I had received a refund, but I checked my wallet (Binance) and saw no deposit from them.

Binance requires both a payment id and address. Looking at the transaction history, I see **no** associated payment ID.

Does that mean they forgot to include payment ID? What can I do to successfuly get the refund? Is it up to Binance or XMR.to? I did email XMR.to asking for help but I feel like it's going to be a battle, so I'd like to be a little proactive.

Thanks

Comment: Did you supply xmr.to with not only a refund address but a payment ID as well?

Comment: @scoobybejesus Yes, I did. I provided xmr.to with 3 things. 1) Their secret key. 2) my payment id. 3) my refund address. I can provide the screenshot of my email with the identifiers redacted if that's helpful?

Comment: I could be wrong/off base, but for the refund, they would need your payment ID from binance (the ID you use to deposit into your Binance account)    I think the refund came back with no payment ID, and landed in Binance's global account.  I'd give Binance the 2 transaction hashes and hope fro the best. (Think f your payment ID as an apt number, while main address is the street address. )

Comment: @Dave great analogy. I did not know to think of it that way. Does this help with security? Anyway, I provided XMR.to **with payment ID** (they even ask for Payment ID, among other things -- https://xmr.to/#faq). I don't know why a service that deals solely with Monero would see a payment ID and know to use it?

Comment: xmr.to gave you a payment ID so they know who sent it in to them. (your apt in the xmr.to building)  But they don't know your payment ID at Binance (your apt# at Binance)  I haven't used xmr.to, but I'd think they should adopt a refund address with payment ID if they don't already.

Comment: Have you asked xmr.to for the tx id so you can check that on the blockchain? Ultimately you will need to work with Binance and xmr.to to try and resolve this.